# doctrine query onetonmany / notIn with objects / symfony forms querybuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, where-clause, query-builder

I am using symfony 2 and doctrine to prefilter a form field type 'entity' with the help of a querybuilder.

My querybuilder should return all products which the user has not already added to a list.
All relations are bidirectionnal.
I have products linked to userIngredients (oneToMany) each linked to one user (manyToOne)

I have come with this so far but it's not working, I get products not added by other users.

```
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.userIngredients', 'i')
        ->where('i.user <> ?1')
        ->setParameter(1,$user);
```

1; Any clue on how to correct this ?

Alternatively, I could select the products I don't want and then reselect those who don't match but using an expression and NotIn seems to only work for strings

```
    $products = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.userIngredients', 'i')
        ->where('i.user = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1,$user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where($this->createQueryBuilder('p')->expr()->notIn('p', $products));
```

2; how could we correct this to make it work with objects ?

3; alternatively : is there a way to pass not a querybuilder but an array of results to symfony form builders ?

Comment: Your original idea seems totally legit to me, although, I have never used the `<>` operator but rather `!=`. Have you tried verifying the `DQL` in profiler?

Comment: it's actually normal it's not working : when retrieving the useringredients of product 1, there might me a useringredient of another user. Hence it's not satisfying the where clause. I would need a condition saying that $user does not belong in the array made of each userIngredient->getUser...

Comment: I think the second one should work but you need to pass the first DQL instead of whole result object. I mean `$dql = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')->leftJoin('p.userIngredients', 'i')...->getQuery();` then `return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')...->expr()->notIn('p', $dql))->getQuery()->getResult();`

Comment: wow, I finally got i, you pointed me in the right direction! thanks so much. I'm posting the solution as a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got thinks thanks to Javad:
(slight modification, I'm using an array result, not dql):

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$ids = $qb
    ->select('p.id')
    ->from('AppBundle:MarketPlace\Product','p','p.id')
    ->leftJoin('p.userIngredients', 'i')
    ->where('i.user = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1,$user)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

//I don't know why I couldn't directly get an array of ids otherwise... if you know how to do better directly from the query, I'm interested (getScalarResult does not make it)
$ids=array_keys($ids);

$result = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where($this->createQueryBuilder('p')->expr()->notIn('p.id', $ids));

return $result;
```